# Genetic algorithms for graph connectivity

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I am a beginner in GA and I would like to represent a connectivity between two nodes of a graph using chromosomes but I am not able to come up with a representation.

I will be grateful if somebody could help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Representation follows function: what are you trying to compute with a genetic algorithm applied to the connectivity of a graph?

Comment: I want to represent a set of nodes with their connectivity that min/max an objective function. But i am stuck on how to represent a chromosome i.e how to encode a node with its direct neighboring node. Am I clear ? thank you for your time and answer.